# Returning Data from a loop using Promises in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the below sequence of the chained loop which I want to return using promises but I get the response before the forEach is executed in my code... Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong... I would like to do it using native Promises and would not prefer to use await/async so I get a better understanding of how Promises function.

```
Details.find(function(err,details){
    if(err){
        res.send(err)
      }else{
          console.log("----------First Promise------------")
          return details
      }
}).then(result1 => {
    result1.forEach(function(item){
        renderData = {}
        OrgChart.findOne({GID:item.gid},function(err,detail){
                console.log("Detail is ------> " + detail.DISPLAY_NAME)
                if(err){
                    res.send(err)
                }else{
                    return detail.DISPLAY_NAME
                }
            }).then( result2 => {
                renderData.gid = result2.DISPLAY_NAME
                renderData.pageouttime = item.pageouttime
                renderData.createdAt = item.createdAt
                renderData.oncall = item.oncall
                renderData.comments = item.comments
                renderData.actionLink = item._id.toString()              
                console.log(renderData)
                dataArr.push(renderData)

            })      
    })
}).then(result3 => {
    console.log("Final Result is ----> " + result3)
    response.data = result3
    res.json(response) 
})
```

Inside the forEach, I want to get a value using a value of the row. I am new to node js and Promises... I want to achieve something like below but using Promises.

Example sequence I want to Achieve through Promises

```
var someArray = []
var DetailsObj = Details.find()
DetailsObj.each(function(item){
   var newMap = {}
   newMap.prop1=item.prop1
   newMap.prop2 = item.prop2
   newMap.prop3 = OrgChart.find({id:item.prop3}).displayName
   someArray.push(newMap)
})
```

Please, can anyone let me know where I am going wrong?

Update 1(Not Working)

```
return Promise.all(result1.map(function(item){
        renderData = {}
        OrgChart.findOne({GID:item.gid},function(err,detail){
                console.log("Detail is ------> " + detail.DISPLAY_NAME)
                if(err){
                    res.send(err)
                }else{
                    return detail.DISPLAY_NAME
                }
            }).then(result2 => {
                renderData.gid = result2.DISPLAY_NAME
                renderData.pageouttime = item.pageouttime
                renderData.createdAt = item.createdAt
                renderData.oncall = item.oncall
                renderData.comments = item.comments
                renderData.actionLink = item._id.toString()              
                console.log(renderData)
                dataArr.push(renderData)
            })      
    }))
```

Still i get an empty array

Update 2 (Added return from the map callback--- Still not Working)

```
return Promise.all(result1.map(function(item){
        renderData = {}
        OrgChart.findOne({GID:item.gid},function(err,detail){
                console.log("Detail is ------> " + detail.DISPLAY_NAME)
                if(err){
                    res.send(err)
                }else{
                    return detail.DISPLAY_NAME
                }
            }).then(result2 => {
                renderData.gid = result2.DISPLAY_NAME
                renderData.pageouttime = item.pageouttime
                renderData.createdAt = item.createdAt
                renderData.oncall = item.oncall
                renderData.comments = item.comments
                renderData.actionLink = item._id.toString()              
                console.log(renderData)
                dataArr.push(renderData)
            }) 
        return dataArr             
    })
)
```

Update 3(Updated after returning from the `then()` callback in the `Promise.all()` block --- Still not Working)

```
  return Promise.all(result1.map(function(item){
        renderData = {}
        OrgChart.findOne({GID:item.gid},function(err,detail){
                console.log("Detail is ------> " + detail.DISPLAY_NAME)
                if(err){
                    res.send(err)
                }else{
                    return detail.DISPLAY_NAME
                }
            }).exec().then(result2 => {
                renderData.gid = result2.DISPLAY_NAME
                renderData.pageouttime = item.pageouttime
                renderData.createdAt = item.createdAt
                renderData.oncall = item.oncall
                renderData.comments = item.comments
                renderData.actionLink = item._id.toString()              

                return renderData
            })            
    })
)
```

Comment: you can try `Promise.all()`, insted of using foreach,
insert your queries into an array, and process it through `Promise.all()`
 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Tried but still no luck ... have put the updated code in that i tried

Comment: @Apoorv Your update misses to `return` the promise from the `map` callback

Comment: @Bergi .. Added the return statement from the map callback ... but still no luck ... have updated above .... i am still getting the below response

{"status":200,"data":[[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]],"message":null}

Comment: I said you need to `return` *the promise* from the callback, as that is what `Promise.all` will be waiting for. It won't wait for an array that is still empty. Just drop the `dataArr` and resolve your promise with the `renderData` (by returning it from the `then` callback)

Comment: i'd recommend you make a proper answer Bergi, it'll make things easier. I also think that promise.all will be the solution for this specific issue

Comment: @Bergi I made the change suggested by you .... but still i am getting the same response "data":[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],

Comment: Is this [sails findOne](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/find-one)?

Comment: Also one tip; `not working` can only be answered by `you're doing something wrong`. not very helpful for anyone. if something is `not working` then you usually expect something but something else happens. You should provide this information. Like I expected .... but got error ... or got ... instead.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should properly [promisify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572) your functions:

```
function findDetails() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Details.find((err, details) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve(details);
        });
    });
}
function findChart(gid) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        OrgChart.findOne({GID:item.gid}, (err, detail) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else resolve(detail);
        });
    });
}
```

or, as your library seems to support for simplicity (notice we're not passing any callbacks!):

```
function findDetails() {
    return Details.find().exec();
}
function findChart(gid) {
    return OrgChart.findOne({GID:item.gid}).exec();
}
```

Now we can build the promise chain from those (notice all the `return` statements!):

```
findDetails().then(details =>
    console.log("----------First Promise------------");
    return Promise.all(details.map(item => {
//  ^^^^^^
        return findChart(item.gid).then(detail => 
//      ^^^^^^
            console.log("Detail is ------> " + detail.DISPLAY_NAME)
            const renderData = {
                gid: detail.DISPLAY_NAME,
                pageouttime: item.pageouttime,
                createdAt: item.createdAt,
                oncall: item.oncall,
                comments: item.comments,
                actionLink: item._id.toString(),
            };
            console.log(renderData);
            return renderData;
//          ^^^^^^
        });
    }));
}).then(dataArr => {
    console.log("Final Result is ----> " + dataArr);
    response.data = dataArr;
    res.json(response);
}, err => {
    res.send(err);
});
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Sails and not sure if that is actually the api that OP is using but [sails documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries#promises) say that promises are an alternative to `exec` so `find` and `findOne` should return a promise without the `exec`

Comment: @HMR Thanks, even simpler then. In any case the point I was trying to make is that no callbacks should be passed to `find`(`One`), only to `then`.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for your solution ... it worked just the way i wanted it to ..... i finally got what you are trying to explain .... if i am not wrong but you mean to say that code block with `findOne` is not behaving as a promise at all ... and after the first block my code is returning a blank array... i really need to get my concepts of Promises in track .... Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

If it is Sails you are using (should add the tag in the question and mention it) then according to the [documentation](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries#promises) it supports promises. But the documentation says that promises are an **alternative** to `exec` So your code should look like this:

```
Details.find()
.then(
  result =>
    Promise.all(
      result.map(
        item=>
          OrgChart.findOne({GID:item.gid})
          .then(//here is where your code is confusing
            // does detail have detail.DISPLAY_NAME.DISPLAY_NAME?
            // I assume it has not
            details=>({
              gid : details.DISPLAY_NAME,
              pageouttime : item.pageouttime,
              createdAt : item.createdAt,
              oncall : item.oncall,
              comments : item.comments,
              actionLink : item._id.toString()
            })
          )
      )
  )  
)
.then(
  results=>{
    console.log("results are:",results);
  }
)
.catch(
  err=>console.error("Something went wrong:",err)
);
```

Comment: No i am not using Sails... the part you are referring to is mongoose syntax ... and yes i should have atleast tagged mongooose

Comment: @Apoorv Ok, should be fine then, sales and mongoose are similar. [Query is a promise](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html): `A Query has a .then() function, and thus can be used as a promise.`  but [exec](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec) also returns a promise. As Bergi stated; you don't need to provide callback functions, only resolve and reject listeners.

Comment: In Mongoose queries are not promises but they have a `.then()` function for `yield and async/await` ... I am not sure what that means .... but if we want a full/fledge promise the documentation says to use `exec()` .....http://mongoosejs.com/docs/4.x/docs/promises.html

Comment: @Apoorv The 5.0.2 documentation literally says: `A Query has a .then() function, and thus can be used as a promise.` is the code provided in the answer giving you errors or unexpected results? I'd try running it in a single file first instead of part of a express like application so you can just run it from the command prompt and debug it (`node --inspect-brk index.js` open deftools in chrome and click on the node icon)

Comment: Yes i just saw that in 5.0.2... but i am currently using 4.13.0 .... i havent tried your solution ... .but will surely try it out .... Thanks again for your help